# Remove even digits from a number with only numerical operations, no list or strings

Tags: python, algorithm, math

For this assignment, I am tasked to:

> 1. Input a number
> 2. Remove even digits from the given number without changing the order of the digits
>
> For example: 123407 will print 137
>
> If a number starts with 246 then it prints 0.

I am not allowed to use strings, lists, functions, packages, recursion, ..., only mathematical operations.

Here is my code so far:

```
POSITION = 1  # give the digit position of the  number 
OUTPUT = 0  # printing the output of the result 
enterNum = int(input('Enter a Number'))  # user inputs  a number 

while enterNum != 0:
    digit = enterNum % 10  # last digit of the number if number is odd 
    enterNum = enterNum / 10  # shift decimal places and remove the digit position 
    if digit % 2 == 1:
        OUTPUT += POSITION * digit  # if digit is odd, add it to the position 
    else:
        continue

print(OUTPUT)
```

I am quite lost on what to do. When the number is 123407, I can only go up to printing 7. I do not know how to store the number in the data type and combine the digits in the end to get 137. Furthermore, I have a hard time looping through the number. It just gives me 7.

Comment: Think of `137 = 1 * 10^2 + 3 * 10^1 + 7 * 10^0`

Comment: but how would you store the individual numbers?

Comment: @m_so99 What you have is pretty close I think. You will need to increment POSITION whenever you get an odd number. Then just something like `OUTPUT += digit + 10**POSITION`

Comment: Start the new number with value 0. In the loop add to new number the elements you see it should be included after multiplying its proper power of `10` depending on its position in the new number.

Comment: @Aaron it partly works except its missing the 3

Comment: @m_so99 sorry, it should be `OUTPUT += digit * 10**POSITION`

Comment: `digit = enterNum % 10  # last digit of the number if number is odd` – it's also the last digit if the number is even.

Comment: Where the code says `OUTPUT += POSITION * digit`, what is the intended purpose of `POSITION`? Do you suppose that the value of `POSITION` ought to change over the course of the program? What is your intended logic? Try to write it out, in plain English words, and relate it to the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```py
num = 123407
res, power = 0, 1

while num:
    last_digit = num % 10
    if last_digit % 2 == 1:
        res += last_digit * power
        power *= 10

    num = num // 10

print(res)
# 137
```

Comment: whats with the double back slash?

Comment: @m_so99 You mean the double *forward* slash?

Comment: It's a way to ensure that you have integer result, not float as with `num / 10`

Answer (score 0):

Tested it out. Starting with your approach and just making a few modifications (see comments for details on modifications):

```
POSITION=0  # This starts at 0, this is because the power of 10 is 0 based (position 0 is the 1's place of the answer)
OUTPUT=0 
enterNum= int(input('Enter a Number'))

while enterNum!=0:
    digit=enterNum%10
    enterNum=enterNum/10 #This will work for python2 I think, but in python3 you will need enterNum//10
    if digit%2==1:
        OUTPUT+=(digit * 10**POSITION) # The digit needs to go in the current place value, if it is the 3rd digit, it needs to be multiplied by 100 (or 10^2).
        POSITION += 1 # Add 1 to the position since we found one (need to place the next OUTPUT digit at the next position)
    else:
        continue

print(OUTPUT)
```

Comment: Can you  explain what modifications you made and why?